# jQuery - Translate String From An Array

Tags: jquery, string

I have an array like this:

```
var en_af = {
    "Hello": "Hallo",
    "World": "Wereld"
};
```

And a string like this:

```
var str = "Hello World";
```

And my expected output:

> Hallo Wereld

So I want to replace the keys with the values.

Comment: None of the answers works.

Comment: Hi, There was a small misunderstanding, Anyhow I've updated my answer. Please try it and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution,

```
var en_af = {
    "Hello": "Hallo",
    "World": "Wereld"
};

var str = "Hello World";  //provide here keys to lookup in en_af array

var keys_from_str=str.split(" "); //making an array of keys from given string.

var output_string="";
for(i=0;i<keys_from_str.length;i++){  
   output_string+=en_af[keys_from_str[i]]+" ";  //get value for respected key from en_af and concatenate with output_string
}
output_string=output_string.trim(); //removing last extra space
console.log(output_string);
```

**Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2pEf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

try, splitting and getting index value of original array:

```
var str = "Hello World";
var res = str.split(" ");

var output="";
for(var i =0; i < res.length-1;i++){
 output += en_af[res[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str_output = "";
```

Start by spliting the keys array

```
var keys_array = str.split(' ');
```

And iterate on it

```
keys_array.each(function(index, value) {
   str_output = str_output + " " + en_af.value;
});
```

Delete first and last spaces

```
$.trim(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.split(" ");
output = en_af.str[0] +" "+ en_af.str[1];
```

you can get the output like Hallo Wereld if strg is "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

```
        var str = "Hello World";
        $(str.split(' ')).each(function (i, v) {
            $('body').append(' ' + en_af[v]);
        });
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B8x4C/